# CSS/Jquery to show hide submenu

Tags: jquery, css

still trying to figure out jQuery and I need some help with a sidebar list.

I am editing this after trying some stuff.

I am trying to have the submenu hidden until a specific list item is moused over, then another menu appears to the side of the sidebar and you are able to mouse over those selections.  I am halfway there but when you mouseout it disappears before you can mouseover any of the items.  I will add hoverIntent but I do not think that is the problem as I need that whole hidden block to also be a trigger to show that element.  I tried Steerpikes solution below but it caused the entire main list to disappear after mouse out.

Here is the structure now:

```
<ul>
<li>Always Showing Element</li>
<li class="trigger">Title that triggers Submenu
<ul>
<li>
Hidden Menu
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

and the script

```
$('li.trigger ul').hide();
 $('li.trigger').hover(function() {
$('li.trigger ul').show();
},
function() {
      $('li.trigger ul').hide();
});
```

So how can I keep it showing while my mouse are over the li.trigger ul li elementes?

Thanks for the help with this!

Nevermind... this works now, I just had the positioning off but now it overlaps a bit and with hoverintent adding a little delay there is no problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The follwing should work. I just wrote something similar 3 minutes ago :)

```
<ul id='menu'>
<li><a href="">Always showing</a></li>
<li><a href="">Always showing Title of Submenu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Hidden until hover over Title </a></li>
</ul>
</li>

$('#menu li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').hide();
});
```

Remember that [`hover()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) takes two arguments - what happens when you mouse in and what happens when you mouse out.

Comment: Hmmm.. not working for me.  When I mouse out the entire list disappears not just the submenu

Comment: Oh ok I got it with this: 
$('li#pages ul li ul').hide(); 
$('li#pages').hover(function() { 
$('li#pages ul li ul').show();}, 
function() { $('li#pages ul li ul').hide();}
);

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using CSS to do this feature.  Since this is for a menu, you want it to be very accessible.  Users that have javascript turned off (think mobile browsers too) or anyone using a screen reader will not be able to use your menu.

Try viewing: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

It is a CSS solution for multi-dropdown menus that should work out great.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use class instead of using id, this is the code it works for me:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menu_box'>
<ul class='menu'>
<li><a href="">Always showing</a></li>
<li><a href="">Always showing Title of Submenu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Hidden until hover over Title </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
$('#menu_box ul li ul').hide(); 
$('#menu_box ul li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to make your root element a block level element, and perform your event handling in that context.